# Retorno de imagem Banco de Dados Json

Tags: php, javascript, banco-de-dados, json, imagem

Inicialmente para esclarecimento, estou tentando cria um app hibrido html, javascript e css.

objetivamente, meu obstáculo é exibir na tela do usuário seu avatar, que esta em um diretório do banco de dados Mysql no meu computador.

Eu consigo enviar a imagem por Json com o metodo FormData sem problemas. Na hora de retornar o login com os dados do usuário ele exibe as informações que armezeno com localStorage.setItem. Mas a imagem ele exibe somente o nome com o caminho do arquivo.

Ja pesquisei muito, quebrei a cabeça e não consegui. Se poderem me ajudar agradeço.
Vou enviar meus códigos

Faz login

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type:'post',                                        //Definimos o método HTTP usado
    dataType: 'json',                                   //Definimos o tipo de retorno
    url: 'http://xxxxx/classes/vlogin.php', //Definindo o arquivo onde serão buscados os dados
    data:{
        nemail: email,
        nsenha: senha,
    },
    success: function(dados){

        if (dados == false){
            $("#btn").show();
            $("#menssagem_login").html("Login ou senha Invalidos");     
        }

        else{
            localStorage.setItem('id', dados[0]);
            localStorage.setItem('nome', dados[1]);
            localStorage.setItem('email', dados[2]);
            localStorage.setItem('estado', dados[3]);
            localStorage.setItem('senha', dados[4]);
            localStorage.setItem('tipo', dados[5]);
            localStorage.setItem('data', dados[6]);
            localStorage.setItem('imagem', dados[7]);

            // var obj = JSON.parse(dados);
            // var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(dados);   //tratar os dados
            // var obj = $.parseJSON(dados);    //tratar os dados
            window.location = "estrutura/perfil.html";
            console.log(dados);
        }
        }
    });
});

    $email =  $_POST['nemail'];
$senha =    $_POST['nsenha'];

$pasta = 'fotos/';

 include "conexao.php";
 $link = conexao();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha' AND ativo = 0";

$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($link));
$vazio = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if($vazio == ''){
echo json_encode(false);
}

else{
$registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
// $registro = mysqli_fetch_object($resultado);

// $imagem1 = scandir($pasta,$imagem);
// $lista_dir = scandir($pasta);
// $img;
// foreach ($lista_dir as $registro['imagem']) {
//  $img; 
// }

$id         = $registro['id'];
$nome       = $registro['nome'];
$email      = $registro['email'];
$estado     = $registro['estado'];
$senha      = $registro['senha'];
$tipo       = $registro['tipo'];
$data       = $registro['data'];
$imagem     = $pasta.$registro['imagem'];

// $imagem= $_FILE[$pasta][ $registro['imagem']];
// $imagem= base64_encode($imagem);

$retorno= array($id,$nome,$email,$estado,$senha,$tipo,$data,$imagem);

echo json_encode($retorno);
// echo json_encode($registro);
}
function carrega_perfil(){

var nome = localStorage.getItem('nome');
var email = localStorage.getItem('email');
var estado = localStorage.getItem('estado');
var tipo = localStorage.getItem('tipo');
var data = localStorage.getItem('data');
var imagem = localStorage.getItem('imagem');

// document.getElementById('status').innerHTML=nome+"<br>"+email;
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML=nome;

document.getElementById('avatar').innerHTML= "<img src="+imagem+" />";
console.log(nome);
```

Comment: Onde vc está tentando mostrar a imagem?

Comment: Opa, eu estava tentando mostrar a imagem em um HTML, não apareceu o codigo

Comment: document.getElementById('avatar').innerHTML= "<img src="+imagem+" />";

Comment: Mas Consegui. Era bem simples a solução.
Na variável $pasta do php onde ficam as imagens eu alterei para o caminho completo do endereço do servidor. Valeu